# Access Drizzle databases through MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, drizzle

This is an odd (probably stupid) question but is it possible to manipulate a Drizzle database through MySQL stored procedures? The reason I need to do this is that I'm migrating my MySQL database (which contains a lot of stored procedures) to Drizzle (which doesn't support stored procedures). This was essentially one of my 'grand' short term ideas for this.

Any ideas for doing this, or some other ones?

Comment: Probably not, according to this: http://wiki.drizzle.org/MySQL_Differences

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an easy way to do this that I'm aware of (speaking as a core Drizzle developer, former MySQL developer and currently at Percona as Director of Server Development). You may be able to get somewhere with Continuent for replicating from MySQL to Drizzle though.

While you may get some success with the FEDERATED or FEDERATEDX engines... I wouldn't bet that your access patterns make that remotely efficient.

The best bet is to move away from stored procedures - they're a maintenance and scalability nightmare anyway (schema versioning is hard, having application code in schema just makes it harder).